A example needed to show that the orthogonal complement is not necessarily a submodule
Let me lay down the definition first:

Let $A_k$ be a $k$-algebra, and $M$ be a $A_k$-module.
A vector space $N \subset M$ is called a submodule of $M$, if
$a \in A, v \in N \implies a \cdot v \in N~~~ \text{(i.e. $A \times N \rightarrow N$ is a module structure of $N$)}$

For some subspace $W \subset V$, we define $W^{\perp}:=\{v \in V ~|~ \langle v,w\rangle = 0\}$, this is called the orthogonal complement of $V$.


Fact: For any vector space $V$ and any subspace $W$ of $V$, we have $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$.
Question:
Our professor prove the Maschke's Theorem (If $G$ is any finite group, then $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is semisimple.). We first let $A:=\mathbb{C}[G]$ and our goal is to prove that $_AA$ is a semisimple module over $A$. Let $V = _AA$, we need to prove that $W \leq V$ (this symbol means that $W$ is a subalgebra of $V$) $\implies$ $\exists C_{W} \leq V$ (this symbol means that $C_{W}$ is a subalgebra of $V$) such that $V = W \oplus C_{W}$.
My professor point out that although we have $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$ and $V = W \oplus C_{W}$, $W^{\perp}$ is not necessarily a submodule of $V$.
My question is what is an example for this (the statement $W^{\perp}$ is not necessarily a submodule of $V$)?

What inner product are you thinking of? There could potentially be a few.  Are you just thinking of the ordinary complex inner product on $\mathbb C^{|G|}$?

Isn't there also another commonly used one that's just $f(vw)$ where $f$ is the augmentation map?

There are a number of things in this post which seem a little mixed up.

The post begins discussing a  $k$-algebra $A_{k}$ where $k$ is presumably some field.
It then states as a fact that if $W\leq V$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$, then $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$ where $W^{\perp} = \{u \in V: \langle u ,w \rangle =0, \forall w \in W\}$.

I assume that in 2., the field $k$ is taken to be $\mathbb C$ and that $\langle -,-\rangle$ is an Hermitian inner product on $V$. (Otherwise the statement of 2. is unlikely to be true).

Next, Mashchke's Theorem is normally stated as a theorem about representations of a finite group $G$, not as a statement about the complete reducibility of the group algebra (though it readily implies this).

Finally, showing that $A = \mathbb C[G]$ is a semisimple left $\mathbb C[G]$-module is not a statement about subalgebra, rather it is the statement that any left ideal $W$ of $A$ has a complement, that is, there exists another left ideal $U$ such that $A = W \oplus U$.


Now let's suppose that $k = \mathbb C$ for the rest of this answer. In that case, we have the following:
Proposition: If $(V, \rho)$ is a finite-dimensional $G$-representation over $\mathbb C$, then there is an inner product $\langle -,-\rangle$ on $V$ for which the action of $G$ has image $\rho(G)\subseteq U(V)$ where
$$
U(V) = \{g \in \text{GL}(V): \langle g(v_1),g(v_2) \rangle = \langle v_1,v_2\rangle\}
$$
Proof: Let $\langle -,-\rangle$ be an arbitrary inner product on $V$. (For example, pick a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $V$ and define $\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{a}_i b_i$ where $v_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$ and $v_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n b_ie_i$).
Now let $\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle_G := |G|^{-1}\sum_{g \in G} \langle g(v_1),g(v_2) \rangle$. To show that $\langle -,-\rangle$ is $G$-invariant, suppose that $h \in G$. Then we have
$$
\begin{split}
\langle h(v_1),h(v_2) \rangle_G &= |G|^{-1}\sum_{g \in G} \langle g(h(v_1)), g(h(v_2)) \rangle \\
&= |G|^{-1}\sum_{k \in G} \langle k(v_1),k(v_2) \rangle \\
&= \langle v_1,v_2 \rangle_G,
\end{split}
$$
where in the second line $k= gh$. Since we sum over all $g \in G$ and right multiplication by $h$ is a bijection from $G$ to itself, $\sum_{g \in G} g= \sum_{g \in G} k$, and hence the equality of the second and third lines.
Now if $v \in V$ then $\langle v,v\rangle_G = |G|^{-1}\sum_{g \in G} \langle g(v),g(v) \rangle >0$ since for each $g \in G$ we have $\langle g(v),g(v)\rangle>0$. Since the $G$-action is linear, it follows that $\langle -,-\rangle_G$ is an Hermitian inner product, and if $U(V)$ denotes the group of linear transformations preserving $\langle -,- \rangle_G$, then $G \subseteq U(V)$.
But it is easy to see that $U(V)$ preserves orthogonal decompositions, that is, if $W\leq V$ so that $V= W\oplus W^{\perp}$ then if $g \in U(V)$ the orthogonal complement of $g(W)$ is just $g(W^{\perp})$, that is, $g(W)^{\perp} = g(W^{\perp})$. In particular, if $g(W)=W$ for all $g \in G\leq U(V)$ then $g(W^{\perp})= W^{\perp}$ for all $g \in G$, and thus every subrepresentation of $V$ has a complement.                       $\square$
Unless $\langle -,-\rangle$ is chosen so that $G \leq U(V)$ however, there is no reason for the orthogonal complement of a subrepresentation to be itself a subrepresentation. If, for example, $G = (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z,+)$ the cyclic group with $3$ elements and $V =\mathbb C^2$ then
$$
\rho(\bar{1}) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & \omega \end{array}\right)
$$
where $\omega = \exp(2 \pi i/3)$ has $\rho(\bar{1})^2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 +\omega\\ 0 & \omega^2 \end{array}\right)$ and $\rho(\bar{1})^3 = I_2$, so that $\rho\colon \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \to \text{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$ yields a $2$-dimensional representation of $G$ on $\mathbb C^2$. Clearly $W = \mathbb Ce_1$ is a subrepresentation, but its orthogonal complement, $\mathbb Ce_2$ is \textit{not} a subrepresentation, rather it is the line $\mathbb C(e_1+ (\omega-1)e_2)$ is the subrepresentation of $\mathbb C^2$ which is a complement to $\mathbb Ce_1$.
